# UDFs with the php api library

Tags: google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I am trying to add a UDF (I've tried both options of inline vs on cloud storage) and always get the same messsage:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalidQuery",
    "message": "Unknown TVF: funcName",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "query"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Unknown TVF: funcName"
 }
}
```

I set the resource via.

```
$udf_resource = new Google_Service_Bigquery_UserDefinedFunctionResource();
$udf_resource->setResourceUri('gs://path/to/bucket/funcName.js');
```

or

```
$udf_resource = new Google_Service_Bigquery_UserDefinedFunctionResource();
$udf_resource->setInlineCode("FUNC_NAME_CODE");
```

both are being inserted into a job query config via.

```
$query_config->setUserDefinedFunctionResources($udf_resource);
```

The udf runs fine via. the Web UI.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

passing array to setUserDefinedFunctionResources(), e.g.

```
$query_config->setUserDefinedFunctionResources([$udf_resource]);
```